# I get ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException - reverse the array

Tags: java

I get the output for the program mentioned below. In addition Ii also encounter an exception as:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at ReverseOrder.main(ReverseOrder.java:15)
```

Why does this happen?

```
public class ReverseOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int anArray[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int anotherArray[]=new int[6];
        for(int i=5,j=0;i>=0;i--,j++)
        {
            anotherArray[j]=anArray[i];
        }
        //System.out.println(anotherArray.length);
        //System.out.println(anotherArray[2]);
        for(int j=0;j<=anotherArray.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(anotherArray[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is here:

```
 for(int j=0;j<=anotherArray.length;j++)
    {
        System.out.println(anotherArray[j]);
    }
```

you are accessing a position out of the array. This happen because method `length` gives you the number of elements in the array, and since the first position of an array is 0 and not 1 you should end the loop on `anotherArray.length - 1` and not `anotherArray.length`.

There are two possible solutions to this where you modify your loop to:

a) `for(int j=0;j<=anotherArray.length - 1;j++)`or

b)`for(int j=0;j<anotherArray.length;j++)`

The latter (b) is preferable, since it has less arithmetic operations on it.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
for(int j=0;j<=anotherArray.length;j++)
```

to

```
for(int j=0;j<anotherArray.length;j++)
```

Since if it's `<=` you'll be going out of bounds.

In Java (and most languages), arrays are zero-based. If you have an array of size `N` then its indexes will be from `0` to `N - 1` (total size of `N`).

Answer (score 2):

change

```
<=anotherArray.length
```

to

```
< anotherArray.length
```

For example, if array is

```
int arr[] = new int[2];
arr.length; // it will be 2, which is [0] and [1] so you can't go upto <=length,
// that way you will access [2] which is invalid and so the exception
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int j=0;j<anotherArray.length;j++)
```

instead of

```
for(int j=0;j<=anotherArray.length;j++)
```

Because arrays are zero-based in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You will get [ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=arrayindexoutofboundsexception&oq=arrayindexoutof&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l2j69i60l2.1947j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) when you try access the element that's out of Array limit.

```
for(int j=0;j<anotherArray.length;j++) {
    System.out.println(anotherArray[j]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use this way to reverse your array in first place. Any way

```
for(int j=0;j<=anotherArray.length;j++) should change to 

for(int j=0;j<anotherArray.length;j++)
```

Consider this too, It is easy.

```
    int anArray[]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int temp=0;
    for (int i=0;i<anArray.length/2;i++){
       temp=anArray[i];
       anArray[i]=anArray[anArray.length-(1+i)];
        anArray[anArray.length-(1+i)]=temp;
    }
```

Now your array is reversed.